# How can getCallerID in android by programatically?

Tags: android

I am making android apps we need callerID ,How can proceed it i.e.  when any user call from android device we want find out callerID.
Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure but just check it out this [link][1] it may help you out


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15564021/2492925

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a BroadcastReceiver and deal with telephony events like this:

```
public class CallListener extends BroadcastReceiver {


private static final String OUTGOING_CALL_ACTION = Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL;


private static boolean isOutgoingCall;
private static String savedNumber;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    int event = -1;
    String action = intent.getAction();


    if (action.equals(OUTGOING_CALL_ACTION)) {

        // get phone number from bundle
        savedNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        isOutgoingCall = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //gets phone's state
        String phoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if(phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {
            isOutgoingCall = false;

            //gets the phone number of this incoming call
            savedNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received phone call from [%s]", savedNumber));

        }
        else if(phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
        {
                // call ended
            Log.i(TAG, TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE);
            savedNumber = null;
            event = InCallManager.CALL_STATE.EVENT_IDLE;
        }
        else if(phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
        {
                // call answered
            if(isOutgoingCall) {
                event = InCallManager.CALL_STATE.EVENT_OUTCALL;
                isOutgoingCall = false;
            }
            else {
                event = InCallManager.CALL_STATE.EVENT_INCALL;
            }

        }

    }


}
```

}

in your manifest just add:

```
<receiver android:name="receivers.CallListener">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: why you declare isOutgoingCall,savedNumber variables are static?

Answer (score 0):

You should use  a Broad cast receiver as follows:

Register your broadcast receiver in manifest file as follows:

```
<receiver android:name="MyOwnBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and next step is to implement it in your code which can be done as follows

```
   public class MyOwnBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   String INCOMING_NUMBER = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
Log.e("incoming phone number is",""+INCOMING_NUMBER);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**create a broadcast receiver class and use incoming intent....**

```
public class Sms_Res extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String num=null;

        num=intent.getStringExtra("incoming_number");
        Toast.makeText(context,num, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

}
```