# How to know if user picked up the phone?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, telephony

I have to program a security functionallity that call 3 determined 
user's contacts when something happens. Once one of those users pick up 
the phone, there won't be more calls.

The problem I found is that there is no way to know if the users is 
answering the call or not.

Up to now I used the code found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990947/detect-the-end-of-an-answered-incoming-call-by-user-in-android-not-declined):

```
     @Override
             public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String 
incomingNumber){

                 switch(state){
                     case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: //Calling
                     Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");
                     one=true;
                     prev_state=state;
                     break;
                     case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:  //Call ended
                         Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_IDLE==>"+incoming_nr);
                         if((prev_state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                             prev_state=state;
                             if(one){
                                 callNext();
                                 one = false;
                             }
                         }
                         break;
                 }
             }
```

Does anybody knows if there is any way to know if a user picked up the 
phone?