# Why my BroacastReceiver does not work?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

The `BroacastReceiver` is supposed to listen to incoming and outgoing phone calls.

Here is the receiver:

```
public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(String number, Date start) {
        Log.e("CyranoActivty","disableBluetooth");
        BluetoothManager.stopBluetooth();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(String number, Date start) {
        Log.e("CyranoActivty","disableBluetooth");
        BluetoothManager.stopBluetooth();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(String number, Date start, Date end) {
        Log.e("CyranoActivty","enableBluetooth");
        BluetoothManager.restartBluetooth();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(String number, Date start, Date end) {
        Log.e("CyranoActivty","enableBluetooth");
        BluetoothManager.restartBluetooth();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(String number, Date start) {
    }

}
```

[here link to the superclass of CallReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564021/1815311)

The receiver is registered in `onCreate()` of the Activity

```
phonecallreceiver = new CallReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
    registerReceiver(phonecallreceiver, filter);
```

Here is my Manifest:

```
     <activity
        android:name="com.cjcornell.samplebluetooth.CyranoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cyrano" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I wonder why do you include **BroadcastReceiver**'s intent-filters inside **Activity** declaration in manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to set the correct permissions in the manifest as well.