# How to get incoming call's network(carrier) details in android

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments

I want get incoming call details in android phone for an example when some one calling my android phone to get details of his number's network(carrier) like that for Airtel Vodefone and docomo etc,
Using this method I am getting all details but not carrier details

```
public String[] callduration(){

    String callername="",type="";
    Cursor managedCursor = null;
    int number = 0,name,duration = 0,calltype = 0,date = 0;
    Uri contacts;

    try {

        contacts = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;

        managedCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(contacts, null, null, null, null);
        number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER); 
        name= managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
        duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        calltype = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        managedCursor.moveToLast();

        callername = managedCursor.getString(name);
        if(callername == null){
             callername = managedCursor.getString(number);
        }

        if (managedCursor.getString(calltype).equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

            type = "Incoming";

        }else if (managedCursor.getString(calltype).equalsIgnoreCase("2")){

            type = "Outgoing";

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return new String[]{callername,managedCursor.getString(number),managedCursor.getString(duration),
                        managedCursor.getString(date),type};
 }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Official tutorial,**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

also refer this,
[How to detect incoming calls, in an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/detecting-an-incoming-call-coming-to-an-android-device)

---

**getSimOperator()** -Returns the MCC+MNC (mobile country code + mobile network code) of the **provider of the SIM.**

---

**In manifest file,**

give below permission,

<
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

Comment: how to do this sir another phone mobile network details how to get using our phone number

Comment: @J Bala Prakash your question only for income call network provider..I am right.

Comment: s sir but like tracking network sir airtel vodefone... which network using income callers? how to do this sir

Comment: spend some time in google. I give exact link & exact keyword.

Comment: link keyword give me sir