# How to increase priority of service in android

Tags: android

I am developing a call blocking application. All features are working well. But in case of call blocking, call has been rejected with a small ring on dialer side. I am using service for call blocking. My question is how can I increase priority of this service in such a way that call is rejected prior any ring on dialer side. I have also used priority="999" in receiver's intent-filter in the manifest. But it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine between a `BroadcastReceiver` with `Service`. Once a call is coming, Android system triggers `BroadcastReceiver` to fire `onReceive()` method. Inside this method, call `context.startService()`. So you don't need to set the priority to your `Service`.

You can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15563921/3922207) about handling an incoming call automatically.

Comment: Same problem occurs sometime. This is not the perfect solution.

Comment: I have to block the number without ring on dialer side. Your solution is working well but sometimes it doesn't work. approx in every 2 out of 10 attempt. How can I get the broadcast before ring ?

Comment: BroadcastReceiver always getting called by system once a event is happening on your device. So that, you can't trigger it before ring. My explanation are refers to the lifecycle of BroadcastReceiver class. Please search on Google about it.

Comment: OK. Can I access phonestatelistener before ring ?

Comment: I don't know, I never test that. You can make your own experiment for that.

Comment: Thanks @ Anggrayudi H