# How to mute incoming rigining sound on Bluetooth headset when incoming call comes?

Tags: android

```
if(audio.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall()){
    audio.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,true);
    audio.setbluetoothsco(true);audio.startBluetoothSco();                        
}
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device

Comment: u mean i have to mute music on call_state_ringing?.

Comment: yes...detect incoming call state and mute music or whatever you want

Comment: but for bluetooth headset its not working.

Comment: ohh actually its a bug.we cannot change bluetooth default ringtone programatically.

Comment: @Mubashshir, is your call getting incoming ringing sound over the bluetooth by this `audio.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,false);`