# Is there any way to identify when the phone rings?

Tags: android

my application records voice, but I wonder if there is a function (either way) to identify when the phone rings? So I can stop giving the audio recording

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15564021/2564847

Answer (score 1):

You need look at TelephoneManager. And put listener on state changed.

```
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING
```