# My Broadcastreceiver seem to detect that a call ended, still doesn't do that it should do. Does anybody see the flaws in my code?

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, listener, call

I would like to make two calls in a row in an android app. Upon clicking button the app calls the first number. I created the broadcastreceiver below, that detects when the first call ends. It should write out that "First call ended" and then call the second number. It does not seem working. Can anybody spot the mistake in my code?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void calling(String phone) {


    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
    callIntent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 1);
    startActivity(callIntent);
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallReciever.class);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243 , intent, 0);
   startActivity(callIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.CallButton);


    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calling("+36309577686");

        }
    });
}

public class CallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context mContext;
    private CustomPhoneStateListener mPhoneListener;
    private String incoming_nr;
    private int prev_state;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;

        if (mPhoneListener == null) {
            mPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();

            // TelephonyManager object
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);


            // Register our listener with TelephonyManager
            telephony.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }

    /* Custom PhoneStateListener */
    class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(incomingNumber)) {
                incoming_nr = incomingNumber;
            }

            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    prev_state = state;
                    break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    prev_state = state;
                    break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if ((prev_state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                        // A call has now ended
                        //it writes out the call end, but does not call. why?
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Call End", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        calling("+36303853440");
                        prev_state = state;
                    }
                    else if ((prev_state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)) {
                        // Rejected or Missed call
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Rejected Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        prev_state = state;
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you register the `BroadcastReceiver`? If it's in the `AndroidManifest.xml` show that part of the XML then.

Comment: @Darwind you can have a look at it here: codeshare.io/GkmbjA

Comment: I guess you've got you question answered by one of the comments on the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are not registering the `CallReciever` anywhere. Try this

```
Button b = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.CallButton);


b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        calling("+36309577686");
        registerReceiver(new CallReceiver());
    }
});
```

Then unregister the receiver on broadcast is received

Comment: but a registered in  the manifest with that:

       <receiver android:name=".MainActivity$CallReciever" />

isn't that engough? (I also tried your suggeston, but than it requires an 'registerReceiver()' method)

Comment: can u post you AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: you can have a look at it here: codeshare.io/GkmbjA

Comment: the problem might be in permission if you are running the app in Android version 6.0 or more. Because by default the permission will be not granted, you have to request permission runtime. If your device android version is greater than 6.0, let me know I will give reference for getting permission at runtime

Comment: no, it is Android 4.4.4  But could you give me the referene? Maybe it works.

Comment: in the code you have sent me, in the registerReceiver(), there should be also an intentfilter, right? (registerReceiver(SomeClass, IntentFilter)). Can it be a solution for the problem? What kind of intentfilter should I create?

Comment: reference for runtime permission https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: refer this SO answer for call detection http://stackoverflow.com/a/15564021/2809326

Comment: thanks. is there an SO answer also for outgoing calls?