# Android - How to detect if user rejected an incoming call?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, incoming-call

I'm making an Android app with incoming calls.
Is there any way in my app, to know if user rejected any incoming call before answering it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect incoming calls, in an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device)

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to add a permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Then you have to register a broadcast receiver in the manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then write in your broadcast receiver's onReceive method:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE); 
    if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
        //If the phone is **Ringing**
    }else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK){
        //If the call is **Received**
    }else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
        //If the call is **Dropped** or **Rejected**
    }
}
```

If the state changes from `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` to `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`, then it will be a missed call.

Like this you have to check the conditions.

Please put a log in those conditions. Then see the logs. I think you will get your answer.

Comment: I've already tried it. But I want to know is there any way to distinguish between call Dropped and Call Rejected ?

Comment: @EvilGuy you have to check the conditions of the phone. I am updating the answer. Please check it.

Comment: I'm sorry if you didn't get my previous comment. I want to detect whether it was a missed call or user rejected the call before answering it. Because in both the cases, the Log in last "if-else" is printed.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since you asked, but I think it might be useful for future reference for others.

If you extract data from Android's calllog (e.g to XML or in your case to a variable in your app) you have two fields of interest:

1) **numbertype** e.g 1 for Incoming, 2 for Outgoing, 3 for missed

2) **duration** (in seconds)

Rejected number is (as you correctly mentioned) treated as numbertype=1. However if you combine numbertype=1 AND duration=0 (since any call answered will have duration>0) then this hopefully solves your problem.

I'm using Android 6, not sure if the types changed since then, but with me the above method works 99.9% of the time. Never managed to hang up the phone in less than a second :)