# BroadcastReceiver for Incoming calls in android doesn't work

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver, incoming-call

I'm trying to develop android app for that can record phone calls. So, in the initial step, I've to see if BroadcastReceiver is getting fired or not.
I've added permissions, receiver tag in AndroidManifest file. I'm testing on OnePlus X. Activity is gets started but BroadcastReceiver doesn't get fired when I get call. What's going wrong here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

PhoneStateReceiver.Java

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Receiver start");
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Incoming Call State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(context,"Ringing State Number is -"+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
            if ((state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Call Received State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Call Idle State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564021/4063532 check this

Comment: where are the permissions?

Comment: @EliasFazel SecondLine from the bottom. I've now moved it to the top because android-studio reported that order Error.

Comment: @OussemaAroua I've tried the code in that link. Still no result. Could it be phone problem?

Comment: i don't think so, did you added the second permission ?

Comment: Permissions should be defined outside the application tag.

Comment: Try to be a little more focused into what is specifically not working before you come to SO and post huge blocks of code.

Comment: It's spelled `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 1):

The permission [`READ_PHONE_STATE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930900/broadcastreciever-for-incoming-calls-in-android-doesnt-work#44930900) is a dangerous permission, if  you are on a marshmallow device you must request runtime permission else your broadcast receiver will not work neither it will throw an error.

That is the most likely the cause of issue from your code because you have correctly registered in the Intent filter other than that there is nothing wrong as it is just a broadcast receiver and should work, i.e get called by the Android system.