# How to get the call coming / hanged event when in Cocos2d Android application

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

**Question**

How to get the call  coming /  hanged event  when in Cocos2d Android application  ?

Because, I want do some action when receive the two event ?

I use coocs2d-x-3.14.1 on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
[How to detect incoming calls, in an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device)

Using this along with JNI calls, you can call c++ functions to carry out the custom actions.

Answer (score 0):

> // This function will be called when the app is inactive. When comes a
>   phone call it's be invoked too.

`AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground()`

> // this function will be called when the app is active again

`AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground()`