# Accept incoming calls Android Studio

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I know many developers ask the same question about how to accept incoming calls on button click.

I'm working on an application like this.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.colorphone.smooth.dialer&hl=en

I searched a lot and successfully implement the feature where application can detect an incoming call ( by following this one [How to detect incoming calls, in an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device/15564021#15564021)) and opens up an activity where user has two choice, whether to accept the incoming call or reject it. The problem the i can't accept/reject the incoming call programmatically. I search a lot but couldn't find the specific solution. If anybody could help me on how could i accept the incoming call programmatically that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try 
through {@link Context#getSystemService Context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE)}
To get a TelecomManager object, and then call acceptRingingCall() method to answer or call endCall() method to reject call.

```
public class TelecomManager {

/**
 * If there is a ringing incoming call, this method accepts the call on behalf of the user.
 *
 * If the incoming call is a video call, the call will be answered with the same video state as
 * the incoming call requests.  This means, for example, that an incoming call requesting
 * {@link VideoProfile#STATE_BIDIRECTIONAL} will be answered, accepting that state.
 *
 * Requires permission: {@link android.Manifest.permission#MODIFY_PHONE_STATE} or
 * {@link android.Manifest.permission#ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS}
 */
//TODO: L-release - need to convert all invocation of ITelecmmService#answerRingingCall to use
// this method (clockwork & gearhead).
@RequiresPermission(anyOf =
        {Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE})
public void acceptRingingCall() {
    try {
        if (isServiceConnected()) {
            getTelecomService().acceptRingingCall(mContext.getPackageName());
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error calling ITelecomService#acceptRingingCall", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the release of Marshmallow, runtime permissions are necessary to access user's phone and user's data.

Now, Coming to your question, To pickup call via grammatically you need 2 Permissions
`Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS` and  `Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE`

but MODIFY_PHONE_STATE is **Not for use by third-party applications**.

Read this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#modify_phone_state)