# How to detect incoming and outgoing calls?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a client app. He want to give android cellphones to his employees. With our app already installed. In our app he wanted to get the record of every phone call.

I know how to do it, I made the BoradcastReceiver. But it is only working in the older version. New Version like Android Nougat and Pie has restriction on it. And I do not any working solution of catching call event.

So Here is what I am doing in my app that is working on older version.

```
 <receiver android:name=".MyCallReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context,"Call Event",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

**Solution I found:**

> So on older version I am watching this toast. but same code not
>   working on the new versions. I Have read that we need to declare same
>   broadcast in code.

So on above R&D I have some confusion

**Confusion:** When declaring in code, will it work even my app is not running at all?

**Another Question:**

> Also we want to track the other calls? is it possible like call of
>   whatsapp and viber?

Please give me detail answer of what to do in case 1 and is it even possible to track calls of whatsapp and viber andother apps like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect incoming calls, in an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't ask multiple questions at once. Asking questions is free. Therefore, you can ask as many questions you want