# Handling incoming phone call ringer when my app's video call is active (Android)

Tags: android

Currently, I am developing an Android app that has a video call (Using WebRTC) features.

My question is how can I handle the original incoming call pop up that draws over my app?

I would like the incoming call just shows on top like a notification or make the status bar green instead of covering the whole of my app during the course of a video call.

Comment: no this feature is handled by android system , we don't change its design in app.

Comment: you cannot override incoming call popups without root access on android.

Comment: @unzila and kkarakk
Thanks for your answers! 
If overriding incoming call popups not a possibility, then how should I properly handle my video call upon receiving a phone call?

Comment: u can check this link for detecting phone call in your app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device