# How can I make android app wait till a phone call is completed?

Tags: android, phone-call, telephonymanager, android-phone-call

I am trying to make multiple phone calls via my android app one after another, by calling a function inside a loop and providing a phone number as a parameter, then the call is made and the function ends and returns to the loop for next phone call and the function with next number is called.

I have tried adding wait() for a certain time which makes the app run as intended, but if call duration is bigger than wait time it doesn't work.

private void callingStart() {
            while (tempAL.size() > 0) {

```
            PhoneNumber = (String) tempAL.get(0);
            PhoneNumber.trim();
            tempAL.remove(callingIndex);
            if (PhoneNumber.length() > 0) {
                finish();
                makePhoneCall(PhoneNumber);                                
            } 
        }
```

}

private void makePhoneCall(String PhoneNumber1) {

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(callresult.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(callresult.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CALL);

    } 
    else {

            if (COUNT == callMade) {
                startActivity(getIntent());
                String dial = "tel:" + PhoneNumber1;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial));
                startActivity(i);
            }            
    }
}
```

I was expecting that call would be made one by one.
But all the calls are made at once or only the last call is made.

I want to make phone call only after the previous call ends.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't wait for the phone call to finish-  you'd register for notification of phone events.  I have some old code at [How to detect incoming calls, in an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device/15564021#15564021) which will show how to know when a call is ended.  When it ends, then you unregister and run whatever code you would have waited for.

Comment: I am new to Android programming, can you please explain in detail what I've to do to make it work.