# Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView com.choudhary.numberreciever.MainActivity.IncomingNumber' on a null object reference

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my app I m detecting the incoming calls phone number , everything working fine but when I m trying to set the phone number in the textview of main activity  I m getting  below errors

Errors

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView com.choudhary.numberreciever.MainActivity.IncomingNumber' on a null object reference
    at com.choudhary.numberreciever.ServiceReceiver$1.onCallStateChanged(ServiceReceiver.java:30)
    at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$1.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:347)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

my Broadcast reciever

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

MainActivity mainActivity;
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
          


            Log.v("incomingNumber", incomingNumber);
            Toast.makeText(context, "incoming number is "+ incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mainActivity.IncomingNumber.setText(incomingNumber);


        }
    },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
}
```

my main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public TextView IncomingNumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IncomingNumber =   (TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_number);

}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564021/7956161

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag because that tag is used for questions about the Android Studio product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize the variable `mainActivity` in your `BroadcastReceiver`. That is why you are getting a NullPointerException.

However, the approach you are using is not good. You should never access UI components (in this case a `TextView`) from a `BroadcastReceiver` directly. The `BroadcastReceiver` should pass the data to your `Activity` and the `Activity` can then manipulate the UI components. If your `BroadcastReceiver` is an inner class of the `Activity`, it can simply call a method on the `Activity` to update the `TextView`.