# Android detecting incoming calls and retrieving data

Tags: java, android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, incoming-call

I need to detect when calls come to the phone and get the name (what is shown when the call comes in, even if it is just a number or SPAM), number and photo.

I tried to do [so](https://gist.github.com/ff760d3354fe0dafa8b9bcc3c1d76525), in the end I had the call detected only after acceptance and never had photo uri. I also tried [this](https://gist.github.com/EvgenyPlaksin/ea197a939b4861fe1213390ec4d529cd), but it doesn't work at all.

**I want to find a not deprecated way to do this and also it should work on new android versions even if the phone is in silent mode** (this is important, I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74093963/18437413) solution, but it doesn't work without a sound)

I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```kotlin
class CustomPhoneStateReceiver(private val onResult: (String, String?, Uri?) -> Unit) : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        println("CustomPhoneStateReceiver onReceive")

        val state = intent?.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
        val incomingNumber = intent?.getStringExtra("incoming_number")

        if (state == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING || state == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
            println("TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING onReceive -> $incomingNumber")
            incomingNumber?.let { number ->
                val (name, photoUri) = getCallerInfo(context, number)
                onResult(number, name, photoUri)
            }
        }
    }
    private fun getCallerInfo(context: Context, phoneNumber: String): Pair<String?, Uri?> {
        val uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber))
        val projection = arrayOf(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI)

        context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null).use { cursor ->
            if (cursor?.moveToFirst() == true) {
                val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)
                val photoIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI)

                val name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
                val photoUri = cursor.getString(photoIndex)?.let { Uri.parse(it) }
                return Pair(name, photoUri)
            }
        }
        val cancellationSignal = CancellationSignal()
        val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = ?",
            arrayOf(CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE.toString()),
            CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC",
            cancellationSignal
        )
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val indexName = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)
            val name = cursor.getString(if (indexName < 0) 0 else indexName)
            println(indexName)
            val indexUri = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_URI)
            val photoUri = cursor.getString(if (indexUri < 0) 0 else indexUri)?.let { Uri.parse(it) }

            cancellationSignal.cancel()
            cursor.close()

            return Pair(name, photoUri)
        }


        return Pair(null, null)
    }
}
```

And in MainActivity.kt:

```kotlin
// ...
    private val onResult: (String, String?, Uri?) -> Unit = { phone, name, photoUri ->
        println("onResult -> $phone, $name, $photoUri ")
        val dataTv = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.data_tv)
        val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView_screenshot)
        val uriString = photoUri.toString().ifBlank { "No photo" }
        val formattedName = name?.ifBlank { phone } ?: phone
        dataTv.text = "phone number: $phone\ncallerName: $formattedName\nimageUri: ${if(uriString == "null") "No photo" else uriString}"
        requestMediaProjection()
    }

    private val receiver = CustomPhoneStateReceiver(onResult)

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED))
// ...
}
```

Comment: from Android 12 we don't get "incoming_number" from intent data and from `getCallerInfo` function it will retrieve from `CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI` query and it gives second last number from call log not current incoming number. Do you have any solution for this?